# Rails ActiveRecord: Can you auto-create a belongs_to association without defining the corresponding has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I essentially have multiple models with a `belongs_to` association to another model, but I don't want to define all the `has_many` relationships on the parent model. Is there a way to create and link this association in one call?

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  # does not have any has_many or has_one associations defined
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thing
end

# in a controller...

thing = @comment.build_thing(thing_params)

if thing.save
  # thing was created but @comment.thing_id was not updated
end

if thing.save && @comment.update(thing: thing)
  # this works, but requires an extra call to update the comment
else
  # now we would have to check which model failed to save
end
```

Is there a simple way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: You can go ahead with thing.save && @comment.update(thing: thing) , this looks good

Comment: This sounds kind of like an artificial problem. If you don't want to define the has_many assocation over and over use inhertiance or mixins.

Comment: It’s more that I want to discourage other developers from querying the has many (`thing.comments`) and encourage/require calling only the belongs to.